# How to start a spark session only if needed

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am fairly new to spark. I have a case where i dont need the executors and other infra until a condition is met.I have the following code

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    try {
      val request = args(0).toString


      // Get the spark session
      val spark = getSparkSession()
      log.info("Running etl Job")
      // Pipeline builder
      val pipeline = new PipelineBuilder().build(request)
      pipeline.execute(spark)
      spark.stop()
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to successfully run", e)
      }
    }
  }
```

The above code creates a spark session and executes an ETL pipeline.
However i have a requirement that i only need to start the pipeline if based on a condition. In the below code, i want to only start the sparksession if a condition is true.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    try {
      val request = args(0).toString
        if(condition) {
          val spark = getSparkSession()
          log.info("Running etl Job")
          // Pipeline builder
          val pipeline = new PipelineBuilder().build(request)
          pipeline.execute(spark)
          spark.stop()
        } else {
          // DO nothing
        }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to successfully run", e)
      }
    }
  }
```

Does this ensure that no sparksession is initiated and no executors are spun up if the condition is false ? If not, is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: Even you have spark session initiated, until you haven't triggered an action there is no actual operations with the data going on.

Comment: right. but wouldnt it create the resources needed as soon as we have a spark session initiated ?

Comment: its a distributed system .. nothing is allocated until action is trigged, spark is lazy .. this is core feature. It will try build a full execution graph, try optimise and then apply actions, so don't worry much about session, actions and transformations would be more important for you

Comment: What @Pavel said is right, but to answer your question, if the condition is false that code won't be called

Comment: thanks @Pavel and Pedro . That is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of lazy evaluation in scala.
In your getSparkSession() function define

```
lazy val spark: SparkSession = ....
```

As per wikipedia, *"Lazy Evaluation is an evaluation strategy which delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed"* .

Few benefits of lazy evaluation are,

1. Lazy evaluation can help to resolve circular dependencies.
2. It can provide performance enhancement by not doing calculations until needed — and they may not be done at all if the calculation is not used.
3. It can increase the response time of applications by postponing the heavy operations until required.

Please refer https://dzone.com/articles/scala-lazy-evaluation to know more.